# Set paper rock scissors win rules without ton of if statments

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I was working on a paper rock scissors challenge, and when I needed to set a function that decides the winner, I felt like writing a lot of if statements that includes every potential case is not practical at all. But after I run a small search, all the codes I had examined used if statements. Isn’t there any better way to do that ?

I will share the code I have below :

```
 //after the user clickes on scissor or paper or rock mymove function runs.
function mymove(choice) {
     let humanchoice = choice.id 
    //a while loop that runs till the computer choice is not the same as the user choice
    while (true){
         let pcnum = Math.random();
         console.log(pcnum);
         let pcchoie = 'paper';

        
         if(pcnum <= 0.33){
         pcchoie = "paper";
      
    } else if(pcnum <= 0.66){
         pcchoie = "scissor"; 
    }else {
         pcchoie = "rock"; 
       
    }
    console.log(pcchoie); 

    
    if(humanchoice == pcchoie){ console.log ("lag");}
    else if(humanchoice != pcchoie){ break;}
}
```

}

Now i need a way to set the rules to make the computer decide who is the winner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could represent the winner logic in an object:

```js
const beatenBy = {
  "scissor": "paper",
  "paper": "rock",
  "rock": "scissor"
};

function decideWinner(humanChoice, pcChoice) {
  if (humanChoice === pcChoice) {
    return "draw";
  }
  else if beatenBy[humanChoice] === pcChoice {
    return "human";
  }
  else {
    return "pc";
  }
}
```